# How to capture data from website as key-value pairs from the website using python?

Tags: python, dictionary, beautifulsoup, key-value

output generated: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5St9.png)
code used to get Model name:[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p35Ta.png)

```
enter code here
test_link = 'https://www.amd.com/en/products/cpu/amd-ryzen-9-3900xt'
r = requests.get(test_link, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'lxml')
whole_data = soup.find('div', class_='fieldset-wrapper')
specifications = []
specifications_value=[]
for variable1 in whole_data.find_all('div', class_='field__label'):
    #print(variable1.text)
    variable1 = variable1.text
    specifications = list(variable1.split('\n'))
    #print(specifications)
for variable2 in whole_data.find_all('div', class_='field__item'):
    #print(variable2.text)
    variable2 = variable2.text
    specifications_value = list(variable2.split('\n'))
    #print(specifications_value)
```

issue:i am getting the data, but in separate variables and for loops, how to map these two variable using key-value pairs? so that i can check conditions like:
if the value is platform then only tale it's value(box processor)

i want to capture the data in such a way that if the 'key' is platform then only capture it's value(boxed processor). similarly for all other 14  tags.

Comment: Please don't include text as screenshots. Stack Overflow has many [formatting features](/help/formatting) you can use to include text such as code, output, etc. in your question. Consider replacing your screenshot of text with a code block containing the actual text.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to iterate through two lists in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663807/how-to-iterate-through-two-lists-in-parallel) You want to iterate over `whole_data.find_all('div', class_='field__label')` and `whole_data.find_all('div', class_='field__item')` simultaneously.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi thank you! yes i want to iterate through these 2. But i want to check also that if the 1st list is == platform then only pick the value from the 2nd list.otherwise leave it blank. for ex: if Product Family is not there then i have to leave it blank. both are in different list how will i map these?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi can you please help

Comment: When you iterate over those two in parallel instead of in separate loops as shown in the link I shared, you will get one value of `specifications` and the corresponding value of `specifications_value`.

Comment: Do you have an example url with a missing value?

Comment: @QHarr thanks for replying. yes i have the URL with missing value:

Comment: @QHarr thanks for replying. yes i have the URL with missing value: https://www.amd.com/en/products/cpu/amd-ryzen-7-3800xt - this url is having all the required things. But other url : https://www.amd.com/en/products/cpu/amd-ryzen-9-3900xt is not having CPU SOCKET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over a list of expected keys and use `:-soup-contains` to target the description node. If that is not None then select the child values. Otherwise, return ''.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

links = ['https://www.amd.com/en/products/cpu/amd-ryzen-7-3800xt',
         'https://www.amd.com/en/products/cpu/amd-ryzen-9-3900xt']

all_keys = ['Platform', 'Product Family', 'Product Line', '# of CPU Cores',
            '# of Threads', 'Max. Boost Clock', 'Base Clock', 'Total L2 Cache', 'Total L3 Cache',
            'Default TDP', 'Processor Technology for CPU Cores', 'Unlocked for Overclocking', 'CPU Socket',
            'Thermal Solution (PIB)', 'Max. Operating Temperature (Tjmax)', 'Launch Date', '*OS Support']

with requests.Session() as s:

    s.headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

    for link in links:

        r = s.get(link)
        soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
        specification = {}

        for key in all_keys:

            spec = soup.select_one(
                f'.field__label:-soup-contains("{key}") + .field__item, .field__label:-soup-contains("{key}") + .field__items .field__item')

            if spec is None:
                specification[key] = ''
            else:
                if key == '*OS Support':
                    specification[key] = [
                        i.text for i in spec.parent.select('.field__item')]
                else:
                    specification[key] = spec.text

        print(specification)
        print()
```

Comment: thank you for this code. As i am new to this, i am not able to understand it. i am breaking it into small parts and trying to understand.

Comment: I look for the elements with class .field__item that have the desired search text e.g. 'Platform'. If that is present, I move to the adjacent element and grab its value or children's values (if OS spec info). If that particular spec description e.g. CPU Socket is not present on a given webpage then the value of spec will be None and so I return ''

Comment: thanks for all the help! i understood it. i hope i am also able to write the code like you one day soon.

Comment: i have 1 more query how can i include Model also as key when i tried with the code it is giving below output:{'Model': [<title>AMD Ryzen™ 7 3800XT | Desktop Processor | AMD</title>]}

Comment: looks like you need to add .text to the end of spec i.e. spec.text when assigning to dictionary.

Comment: i have added code and output images in the question. when i am trying to do .text . it is giving error :Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\project1_AMD\Test.py", line 28, in <module>
    specification[key] = spec.text
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 2253, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'text'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

Comment: Is there an url with Model included?

Comment: i got it.. i had to add logic in the IF CONDITION with 'None' thank you @Qharr .still trying to get it's text... i will get that also eventually.

Comment: we have to use .select('Title') to get model name. Hence i gave key as Model and waited for its value to come as 'None' then in that "IF" condition i added:        if spec is None:
            specification[key] = ''
            if key == 'Model':
                spec = soup.select('Title')
                specification[key] = [i.text for i in spec]
                print(spec)

Comment: `soup.select_one('.page-title')`

Comment: thank you so much for all the help! i have one more question... model_list = sub_url + model_list
        #print(model_list)  ----it is giving me list of url without any comma
        model_links.append(model_list) ------it is giving me model_links = ['https://www.amd.com/en/products/cpu/amd-ryzen-9-3900xt']
['https://www.amd.com/en/products/cpu/amd-ryzen-7-3800xt']
But i want model_links = ['https://www.amd.com/en/products/cpu/amd-ryzen-9-3900xt','https://www.amd.com/en/products/cpu/amd-ryzen-7-3800xt'] as single list

Comment: please open a new question with all that info and your code. It is difficult to follow in comments and others are less likely to see.